# AWS Free Tier Termination Projected Costs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cost-explorer

Is there a way to see what the past costs for an account would be without any free-tier discounting, or what the project monthly costs for that account will be after the free-tier has terminated?

I see no obvious strategy for this in the billing dashboard nor AWS forums, and got nowhere with any of my searches. Since this basically affects *everyone*, at one time or another, with a bias towards new users (the majority of people affected by the Free Tier), I'd expect there to be a tool for this. But, then, AWS billing is not the most intuitive for those very same new users.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked around inside AWS cost explorer? https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/aws-cost-explorer/

Answer (score 1):

It certainly is not the most intuitive, as you put it, indeed :D
The best option I know of is to check your bills for all the items under the free tier and then use AWS Pricing Calculator at https://calculator.aws/#/ to create estimates of all the services you used and sum them up.

For some services that are not listed in the Pricing Calculator (like most VPC resources) you'll have to look them up on their individual product pages and do the maths (googling "aws *product-name* pricing" usually gets you there quickly...